# I need to bake frozen breakfast bowls in an oven because I will not have access to an microwave. How long should they bake & at what temp.?

Tags: breakfast

I need to bake frozen breakfast bowls in an oven because I will not have access to a microwave.  They will be in pyrex bowls.  How long should they bake and at what temperature?  They can be thawed first.  Approx. 3 cups food.

Comment: "Breakfast bowl" means different things to different people.  What's in yours, and in what proportions?

Comment: Potatoes, sausage crumble, eggs and cheese.

Comment: Is everything cooked and then frozen, so you are just reheating (and maybe melting the cheese?)

Comment: Very different - I've heard it used to refer to something containing oats, fruit etc!

Answer (score 1):

You will certainly have to thaw the food and let it come to room temperature, else you risk it breaking. Don't put frozen or fridge-cold glass vessels in a hot oven.

For the temperature, you can take 175 C, or 350 F. This is a catch-all temperature, very few dishes will fail at it.

You cannot bake them by time. You just have to keep checking on your food and take it out when it is ready. There is no way to predict how long it will take. The exception is, if it is a recipe where longer is better, such as some stews, you can just give it 2 hours to be certain it will be well done. But this won't work for most dishes - you just cook until it is cooked.

Comment: source for the fact that Pyrex-branded glass vessels sold in the US aren't oven-safe? the covers are not, but the actual glass most definitely is. From Pyrex US's web site: *Pyrex® glassware is designed to be as versatile as it is long lasting.  You can use it to prepare, store, cook, bake, warm or reheat food—in pre-heated conventional and convection ovens, or in microwaves.*

Comment: @Esther see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrex) for the change in glass type. It doesn't state "not oven safe" in so many words, but I have always been taught that borosilicate is the oven-safe glass, and soda-lime isn't.

Comment: Pyrex explicitly says that their glass is oven-safe, and everyone I know who used it in ovens had exactly the experience you'd expect. Apparently soda-lime glass can be oven safe as well.

Comment: Tempered soda-lime is oven safe, and that's what US pyrex has tended to be. But it's much more susceptible to thermal shock than borosilicate so it's much more at risk when placed cold on hot wire shelves. *Not* preheating the oven would be a good idea; placing the dish on a room temperature baking sheet for more even heating would be some help. Ordinary glass tableware can be heated  in the oven from cold as can jars and bottles

Comment: ... Defrosting in the fridge overnight will be good for even reheating without burning the top. It may not be enough and you may need to cover

Comment: @Esther thanks, then it seems that there is more to glass than I knew. Edited.